# Complete XML Document from Postgres data

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.4

I'm using Postgres XML functions to output a nested xml structure and I get how to create the structure I want at the row level:

```
select xmlelement(
       name row,
       xmlforest(
                 message_id,
                 time_stamp,
                 xmlforest(message_id, clordid, securityid) as block,   
       clordid,
       symbol))
from flat_messages limit 2
```

giving this output:

```
<row>
     <message_id>1</message_id>
     <time_stamp>2015-04-23T14:57:40+01:00</time_stamp>
     <block>
         <message_id>1</message_id>
         <clordid>SV9869385</clordid>
         <securityid>GB0008762899</securityid>
     </block>
     <clordid>SV9869385</clordid>
     <symbol>BG.</symbol>
 </row>
 <row>...

 </row>
```

However, I need to output all the results as a valid XML document with a root element wrapping the whole results set:

```
<results>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
</results>
```

I can do this by adding the start and end  tags after the data is output but I'm sure there must be some way to add the start and end tags to the query. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`xmlagg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-XMLAGG) and another `xmlelement()` to achieve this:

```
select xmlelement(name results, xmlagg(xmlelement(
   name row,
   xmlforest(
             message_id,
             time_stamp,
             xmlforest(message_id, clordid, securityid) as block,   
   clordid,
   symbol)))
from flat_messages limit 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good pattern to make a query returning an XML values coming from a table.